# Reverse Proxy Server not forwarding one web site, but ok for others

Tags: linux, ssl, webserver, nginx, reverse-proxy

To set my level, I'm a Raspberry Pi and Linux experimenter, and not an experienced network administrator.  To get this far I have used the web and several tutorials.  I'm learning, but sometime I follow without completely understanding the instructions.

I have a NginX Reverse Proxy Server (RPS) set up on my local network.  We have several web servers on that network with external IP addresses: two on Windows Server IIS (mydomain and mydomain3), one on Linux Apache (mydomain2) and one on a Pi running NginX (newdomain).  For the first three the RPS is working perfectly, but not for the NginX Pi web.  The IIS and Apache webs do not have SSL certs installed.  However, the NginX server does have LetsEncrypt SSL certs installed.

When we get to [www.newdomain.xxx](http://www.newdomain.xxx) from the web using Firefox, we get this message "Secure Connection Failed".  From Edge, "Hmmm… can't reach this page.  The connection was reset.".  However directly from the local network, ie bypassing the RPS, it works, returning my PHP index page.

We suspect it may have something to do with the SSL certs being on the NginX web server, but not on the RPS server????

Thanks for any ideas/help with this issue....RDK

Below are the conf files for the RPS and the NginX web server:

**Reverse Proxy Server conf File:**

cat  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rev-proxy.conf

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

log_format xxx '$remote_user $remote_port $remote_addr $host [$time_local] '
                 '"$uri" $server_protocol $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_user_agent"';

upstream www.mydomain.xxx {
          server 10.0.45.121:80;
}

upstream www.mydomain2.xxx {
          server 10.0.45.52:80;
}

upstream www.mydomain3.xxx {
          server 10.0.45.121:80;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  www.mydomain.xxx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/x1_access.log xxx;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://www.mydomain.xxx;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  www.mydomain2.xxx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/x2_access.log xxx;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://www.mydomain2.xxx;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  newdomain.xxx www.newdomain.xxx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/xn_access.log xxx;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.0.45.125:80;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain3.xxx www.mydomain3.xxx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/x3_access.log xxx;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://www.mydomain3.xxx;
        }
}
```

**NewDomain NginX webserver config file**

cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/newdomain.xxx

```
log_format xxx1 '$remote_user $remote_addr $host [$time_local] '
                '"$uri" $server_protocol $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_user_agent"';

server {
    server_name newdomain.xxx www.newdomain.xxx mail.newdomain.xxx;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/XL_EM_access.log xxx1;
    root /var/www/newdomain.xxx/public-html;
    include /etc/nginx/template/letsencrypt.conf;

# Not passing files from this directory to php-fpm
# serving them as static content instead
    location ^~ /uploads/ {}
    charset utf-8;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/newdomain.xxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/newdomain.xxx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = mail.newdomain.xxx) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.newdomain.xxx) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = newdomain.xxx) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    access_log /var/log/nginx/XL_EM_access.log xxx1;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name newdomain.xxx www.newdomain.xxx mail.newdomain.xxx;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

Comment: When you bypass the the RPC and are able to connect, are you using a local network address or are you still accessing from www.newdomain.xxx  because it sounds like you are being blocked by a firewall

Comment: When I bypass the RPS I'm using a local address from a computer on the local network.

Comment: Since the RPS is working for the three other sites which are coming in via the internet,  it does not seem that the Firewall could blocking just this one site??

Comment: ....no ideas or comments on this issue?